# Calling generic method from subclass in java

Tags: java, generics

I'm new to generics and here is my problem:

```
public class Tree<T> {
    public Collection<Tree<T>> getSubTrees(){};
    public Tree<T> getTree(T element){}
}


public class DataTree extends Tree<Data>{
    public void someMethod(){
        DataTree dataTree = this.getTree(root) ;// type mismatch
        Collection<DataTree> leafs = this.getSubTrees(); //type mismatch 

        //following works 
        Tree<Data> dataTree = this.getTree(root);
        Collection<Tree<Data>> leafs = this.getSubTrees();
    }
}
```

Can you tell me why I got such errors or how to correctly cast Tree<Data> to DataTree to call DataTree specific methods?

Answer (score 5):

`DataTree` is `Tree<Data>` but `Tree<Data>` **is not always** `DataTree`.

You are returning `Tree<T>`, not `DataTree`. Base class cannot be casted to derrived class.

Comment: The traditional way to fix this, by the way, is to add an additional generic parameter to `Tree`: something like `Tree<E, T extends Tree<E>>`, and then to have the children be of type `T`.  Then you can "tie the knot" by saying `class DataTree extends Tree<Data, DataTree>`.

Answer (score -1):

what is root??? is it a Data Element??

Try Type casting the
     DataTree dataTree = (DataTree)this.getTree(root)

well i think Inheritance hierarchy will not support this , but still you can try .

Comment: here you are trying to cast your base class to derived class, that will not work , try fix that first